# Definitions on ratio and root tests

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

My textbook has some definitions on these ratio and root tests however isn't that rigorous and I am looking for something more complete:

1. State the ratio test
2. State the root test

Would someone mind giving a CLEAR, and complete answer/definition to the above?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Test

Comment: Thanks Carl, however could you put it here and in answering it more in a sentence format than just the proof?

Comment: Carl, the definition was not so clear It just states some assumptions hwoever by stating can you do it in a sentence or 2?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ be a series with positive terms and take the limit of successive quotients of terms: 
$$ L=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}.$$ 
The **Ratio Test** says:

1. If $L<1$, the series converges.
2. If $L>1$, the series diverges
3. If $L=1$, the test fails.

Heuristically, when $k$ is large, the series looks like a geometric series with ratio $L$.

When do you use the Ratio Test? If ratios are fractions, and they tend to simplify nicely *if the top and bottom contain products or powers*.

---

Let $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ be a series with positive terms and take the limit of roots of terms:
$$
R=\lim_{k\to \infty} \sqrt[k]{a_k}.
$$
The **Root Test** says:

1. If $R<1$, the series converges.
2. If $R>1$, the series diverges
3. If $R=1$, the test fails.

Heuristically, when $k$ is large,  $\sqrt[k]{a_k}\sim R$, so $a_k \sim R^k$. This says that the series is approximately geometric for large $k$.

When do you use the Root Test? If the general term of the series has lots of $n^{\rm th}$ powers, since these will simplify when you take the $n^{\rm th}$ root.