# Quotient criterion and root criterion when can they not be used?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just a quick question that puzzles me.
As the title already states, I'd like to know/understand when (and why) the quotient criterion (aka D'Alembert criterion) and / or the root criterion, that are used in order to determine whether a series converges or not, cannot be used.

Comment: The ratio test (as the D'Alembert criterion is usually called, in my experience) and the root test are stated as theorems and hence are always true. Since they are always true, they can always be **used**, but they may not help you get an **answer**. The theorems themselves explicitly state conditions under which they cannot determine convergence or divergence. You might also find that you cannot apply a test because it is too difficult for you to calculate the limit that the theorem asks for. So your question was answered before you asked or is unanswerable. What was your question, actually?

Comment: Sorry for coming back to you so late, I completely forgot about this thread. While our professor introduced the two tests and showed us how they work/are applied, he never showed us more beyond that. So I never knew that these exceptions were built into the theorems. He did show us one thing however, which is that in the case of sum(1/(k^a)) while a is an element of the reals, the two tests don't work. My question was if there are any other such cases.

Comment: We don't know what your professor told you. [Here is a statement of the ratio test](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408s/m408d/CurrentWeb/LM11-6-2.php) and [here is the root test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/roottest.aspx). Note that each test requires you to find a limit, so if the limit **does not exist** then technically the test is inconclusive. And if the limit is $1$ the test is inconclusive. There are also versions of the test that use lim sup and/or lim inf that sometimes work when the plain limit doesn't.

Comment: Another statement of the root test: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3156879/139123

Comment: Statements of slightly different forms of the tests: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1661607/139123 ... Note the lack of absolute value signs, which means if you have a series $\sum b_k$ with positive and negative terms then you have to set $a_k = \lvert b_k\rvert$ so that you can apply these versions of the tests to $\sum a_k.$

Comment: Do any of those statements of the ratio and root tests look like what your professor told you? Do they provide the missing clues you were looking for?

Comment: oh my god thank you. I completely misunderstood what our prof was trying to say. THANK YOU :)))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the statements of both the ratio test and the root test, we can actually prove that in some cases these tests can not give any information on whether the series converges or diverges, namely when the upper limit of the associated sequence equals 1.

Consider the sequences $1/n$ and $1/n^2$; by applying the ratio and the root tests we obtain that the upper limit is always 1. However it is a well known fact that $\sum 1/n$ diverges whereas $\sum 1/n^2$ converges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I have heard that in the case of sum(1/(k^a)), while a is an element of the reals, the two tests do not work. Are there any other such examples?

Comment: ok just to note my confusion has been cleared up just now in the comment section of this post. again thank you for your answer